# Tile drill head shorted electrics but they still work

Tags: electrical, drywall

I was re hanging a kitchen cabinet and when drilling a third hole for the bracket the electrics tripped. However turned them back on and every socket in the kitchen still works. I didn’t put a screw in the hole but put a rawl plug in as it’s plastic. The house was built in 2007 in UK and is a dot dab wall,the drill hole is about 1.25”.
Anyway I need to know if this is likely to cause a fire or electrocute someone? Obviously if I have to cut a hole in the wall to check it which will be a pain to re hang the cabinet.Or will the electrics just trip if something is wrong?

Comment: Just to try to add a little extra weight to the answers below telling you to fix this and not ignore it - if this starts a fire and your insurance finds out that it was caused by your "negligence" you may have trouble getting a full settlement from them ... Since you're in the UK and your wiring is probably in conduit buried in the wall, it would probably be easiest to simply pull the existing damaged wiring out and pull a new cable or set of wires in its place.

Answer (score 6):

If your drilling caused the electrics to trip, then you shorted something to something. The only way you can have done so is by drilling through some insulation, but it looks like you managed to not completely sever the wire.

So now you have uninsulated copper of unknown thickness supplying some part of your kitchen wiring. I see two potential issues:

- The damaged copper could be significantly thinner than it should be, and therefore capable of carrying less current than normal, so it could cause a hot-spot, maybe enough to cause a fire.
- The screw may be providing a path where arcing between the conductors is likely, again increasing the chance of a fire.

Do *not* just leave this and hope nothing happens; you need to get that section of wiring checked and fixed (by a competent electrician).

It's a pain, but you've learned a lesson - use a cable/pipe finder when drilling in the walls, and don't assume that just because nothing has tripped, everything is OK.

Answer (score 4):

You most likely damaged a wire in the wall. Unless something else happened on that circuit at that same moment.

You **must** check the possible damage, remove the cabinet and dig down to find out. TURN OFF the power to that circuit.

If you leave it, then either moisture or movement could cause an issue, at worst a fire.